Stereographic Projection Using a One-Sheeted Hyperboloid
This is in reference to the stereographic projection of a one-sheeted hyperboloid, as detailed on page 199 of this book.
The author visualises the inversive Minkowskian plane by using a stereographic projection. He considers a three-dimensional space and assumes that $z = 0$ is the Minkowskian plane (denoted by $\pi$). Further, he considers the one sheeted hyperboloid $\gamma$:
$$x^2-y^2+z^2-z=0$$
which touches the plane $\pi$ at the origin. The point $(0,0,1)$ is considered to be the point of projection (analogous to the north pole of the Riemann sphere). Then, he maps a point $A(x,y,z)$ on $\pi$ to a point $A'(X,Y,Z)$ on $\gamma$ through the following projection:
$$
X=\frac{x}{x^2-y^2+1}
\hspace{2cm}
Y=\frac{y}{x^2-y^2+1}
\hspace{2cm}
Z=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2-y^2+1}
$$
$A'$ is actually the point of intersection of the line joining $A$ and $(0,0,1)$. Clearly, this projection is continuous and also unique.
The author then claims: "The stereographic projection associates every point of $\pi$ a unique point of $\gamma$".
This is the part that I do not understand. It is quite clear to me that for any point on the plane $\pi$ with $x^2-y^2+1=0$, there is no corresponding point on the hyperboloid $\gamma$. This in fact is the hyperbola $x^2-y^2+1=0$, which acts as an asymptote to the hyperboloid. The line joining the north pole to any point on this hyperbola will never intersect the hyperboloid. How did the author claim that every point of $\pi$ is mapped to a unique point of $\gamma$? What am I missing?
As a side note, it can be observed that this association is not "onto". Specifically, no point of $\pi$ maps to the lines $x+y=0$ and $x-y=0$ at $z=1$ on the hyperboloid. This is resolved by introducing two fictitious lines at infinity to $\pi$ (analogous to the point at infinity in the case of the Riemann Sphere). Considering this along with the aforementioned statement, it can be claimed that the projection from this (extended) plane $\pi'$ to the hyperboloid $\gamma$ is bijective. I do not have confusion in understanding this, however.
screenshot
